# Can every multiple of $3$ be written as sum of a prime number and a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can every multiple of three be written as sum of a prime number and a square number?
That is, $3n=p+s^2$, where $n, s \in {\mathbb N}$ and $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What evidence do you see to suggest this property of numbers?

Comment: No, and the smallest counterexample is under $500$.

Comment: Relevant entry in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A014090 . In particular, limiting to just multiples of 3, we have 324, 771, 1089, 1521, ... as the first few multiples of three that can't be written as a sum of a prime and a square.

Comment: Below 5 million, the only counterexample that's not a square is 771. Is 771 the only non-square counterexample?

Comment: In light of B. Mehta's answer, http://oeis.org/A020495 is also relevant, in particular the entry $771$ in it.

Comment: @B.Mehta, my last comment came one second after yours!

Comment: Great minds! ;)

Comment: $771$ remains the only non-square counterexample below 100 million...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. For instance, try $324=18^2$. If $324 = p + n^2$, then $p = (18-n)(18+n)$. But $p$ is prime and $18-n < 18+n$, so $18-n=1$ and $n=17$. But we can check that $324-17^2 = 35$, which is not a prime.

Comment: Why must $p = (18 - n)(18 + n)$? Is it because $324 = p + n^2$ is equivalent to $324 - n^2 = p$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, then difference of two squares.